# Using reflexive verb "vorstellen" in infinitive construction

Tags: verb, infinitive, reflexive

"I can imagine that." translates to

> Ich kann mir das vorstellen.

If I want to say "It is hard to imagine that he is only 20 years old.", would it be

> (a) Es ist schwer vorzustellen, dass er nur 20 Jahre alt ist.

or

> (b) Es ist schwer **sich** vorzustellen, dass er nur 20 Jahre alt ist.

or does neither of them work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the question refers to the use of the verb, particularly how to put the reflexive:

> Es ist schwer, sich vorzustellen, dass er nur 20 Jahre alt ist.

Otherwise, see collapsar's answer.

Answer (score 5):

In the given context, you'd rather use `glauben` instead of `vorstellen`:

> Ich kann es kaum glauben / Es ist kaum zu glauben, daß er nur/erst 20 Jahre alt ist

Using an adjective, an alternate phrasing is possible:

> Es ist schwer/kaum vorstellbar, daß er nur/erst 20 Jahre alt ist.